# Menu-based Caesar Cipher with encryption and decryption

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I am about to start a very large project in Ruby. To get myself in the Ruby mindset I have been doing all of my homework and other side work in Ruby. I am hoping that some of you who know Ruby very well can look at this small program I have written and point out areas that aren't written in a Ruby-like fashion. Any and all tips and criticisms would be appreciated.

This program is a menu-based Caesar Cipher with encryption and decryption.

```
KEY = 3 
$caesar_map = {}

#initializes the caesar_map and reads input from the user
#starting point of the program
def init()
  #create empty hashes
  plain_alphabet  = {}
  cipher_alphabet = {}

  #fill in the alphabet hashes with the letter and its position
  #in the english alphabet
  "a".upto("z") {|x| plain_alphabet[x]  = ((x[0] - "a"[0]) % 26) }
  "A".upto("Z") {|x| cipher_alphabet[x] = ((x[0] - "A"[0]) % 26) }

  #fill in the caesar_map, maps every letter KEY positions
  #to the right in the alphabet
  plain_alphabet.each do |k,v|
    $caesar_map[k] = cipher_alphabet.index((v+KEY) % 26)
    #puts "key: #{k} mapped value: #{cipher_alphabet.index((v+3) % 26)}"
  end
  #special case, I want spaces to be maintained in the messages
  $caesar_map[" "] = " "

  #print menu
  choice = -1
  while(choice != 3)
    puts "What would you like to do?"
    puts "\n1. Encrypt a message"
    puts "\n2. Decrypt a message"
    puts "\n3. Exit\n"

    choice = Integer(gets.chomp)

    if(choice == 1)
      puts "Please enter a message you would like to Encrypt\n"
      message = gets.chomp
      encrypt(message)
    elsif(choice == 2)
      puts "Please enter a message you would like to Decrypt\n"
      message = gets.chomp
      decrypt(message)
    elsif(choice == 3)
      abort("Exiting...")
    else
      puts "You didn't enter a valid choice. Enter a number between 1..3\n"
    end
  end
end

#encrypts a plaintext message using the caesar cipher
def encrypt(plaintext)
  #make sure the message is in lowercase
  plaintext.downcase!
  ciphertext = ""

  #fill in the ciphertext with mapping information in the caesar_map
  plaintext.split("").each do |c|
    ciphertext += $caesar_map[c]
  end

  #print the encrypted ciphertext
    puts "\n plaintext: #{plaintext}\nciphertext: #{ciphertext}\n\n"
end

#decrypts a ciphertext message using the caesar cipher
def decrypt(ciphertext)
  #make sure the ciphertext is in uppercase
  ciphertext.upcase!
  plaintext = ""

  #fill in the plaintext with mapping information in the caesar_map
  ciphertext.split("").each do |c|
    plaintext += $caesar_map.index c
  end

  #print the decrypted plaintext
  puts "\n ciphertext: #{ciphertext}\n plaintext: #{plaintext}\n\n"
end

#start the program
init()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some points about making your code look more like idiomatic Ruby:

- Use `nil`.

  ```
  choice = -1
  ```

  should be

  ```
  choice = nil
  ```
- Don't wrap your conditional in brackets:

  ```
  while(choice != 3)
  if(choice == 1)
  ```

  should be

  ```
  while choice != 3
  if choice == 1
  ```
- Instead of initializing a variable to an empty array, use `map` to convert one array directly into the new form and use *that* to initialize your variable:

  <strike>Instead of this:</strike> Hashes != arrays, sorry. The principal still applies, even if this example isn't equivalent:

  ```
   #create empty hashes
   plain_alphabet  = {}
   cipher_alphabet = {} 

  "a".upto("z") {|x| plain_alphabet[x]  = ((x[0] - "a"[0]) % 26) }
  "A".upto("Z") {|x| cipher_alphabet[x] = ((x[0] - "A"[0]) % 26) }
  ```

  do this:

  ```
  plain_alphabet  = ("a".."z").map { |x| (x[0] - "a"[0]) % 26 }
  cipher_alphabet = ("A".."Z").map { |x| (x[0] - "A"[0]) % 26 }
  ```

  And instead of this:

  ```
  ciphertext = ""

  #fill in the ciphertext with mapping information in the caesar_map
  plaintext.split("").each do |c|
    ciphertext += $caesar_map[c]
  end
  ```

  do this:

  ```
  ciphertext = plaintext.split("").map { |c| $ceasar_map[c] }.join
  ```
- Use `case` when appropriate; rewrite your if/elsif/elsif/else as:

  ```
  case choice
  when 1:
    # ...
  when 2:
    # ...         
  when 3:
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
  ```

Answer (score 5):

I'd initialize with something closer to this (although I might inline the two arrays):

```
plain_alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
cipher_alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a.rotate KEY
$caesar_map = Hash[plain_alphabet.zip cipher_alphabet]
```

The en/decryption (which could likely be handled by the built-in `tr` method) might look more like:

```
plaintext.split("").inject("") {|s, c| s << $caesar_map[c]}
```

I'd put the whole thing in a class, too; skip the global.

Comment: oh wow, that is a lot simpler. Then I dont have to maintain the position, because the array with already be mapped to the right letter

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I don't know why you'd need to; it's a simple substitution--what do you need the position for? I could just be missing something. Ninja edit!

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you would place this in a class? It seems too small of a program to specialize in any way.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Why *wouldn't* you? But to elaborate, it has class-like behavior, encryption is a general-purpose concept with multiple implementations, has multiple potential extension points, etc. Why is everything you did encapsulated in methods except for a constant and a global? Clearly you saw the need for *some* encapsulation--would putting a `class Foo` around it have been significantly different? For a trivial extra effort it could have been a module/mixin or class with better encapsulation and semantics.

Answer (score 4):

```
KEY = 3 
$caesar_map = {}
```

In Ruby, like most languages, global variables are often a sign of bad design. In this making `$caesar_map` global makes it difficult to use your caeser cipher with different keys (though your program isn't layed out to support that anyway (and you even made `KEY constant`)) because in order to do that you'd have to override the global variable each time you want to use a different key.

I would recommend to create a class which takes the key as a parameter and then creates the map as a parameter. So you could create multiple instances with different keys and then use their `encode` and `decode` methods without them affecting each other.

Except that pre-calculating the mappings between characters seems completely unnecessary to me, so that's not even necesarry. You could just write `encode` and `decode` so that they take the key as a parameter and just do the translation without a map. This way you could call the methods without having to initialize any global data structures or objects. And you could just implement `decode` by calling `encode` with a negative key, which greatly simplifies your implementation and gets rid of code duplication.

---

Further your `encode` and `decode` methods should return string rather than printing their results. It is a good design practice to seperate the places that do IO from the places that calculate stuff. That makes it easier to reuse your logic-methods.

Also you shouldn't call your `init` method `init`. That name suggests that all it does is initializing somethign (say `$caesar_map`), but in fact it does everything. A more appropriate name might be `main`. Or you could just get rid of the method altogether.

---

```
"a".upto("z") {|x| plain_alphabet[x]  = ((x[0] - "a"[0]) % 26) }
"A".upto("Z") {|x| cipher_alphabet[x] = ((x[0] - "A"[0]) % 26) }
```

As I already said, you don't really need to precalculate anything, so this becomes superfluous, but here's some comments for when you write similar code in the future:

`"a"[0]` returns `"a"` in ruby 1.9, so you should use `.bytes[0]` instead of just `[0]` for 1.9 compatibility. Also the `% 26` is completely unnecessary here as the number will already be between 0 and 26.

And as has already been pointed out by Dave, using `map` or other higher-order functions for things like this is a lot more idiomatic. When you want to build hashes like this, you might also take advantage of the fact that `Hash.new` takes a block.

---

```
$caesar_map[" "] = " "
```

You special case " ", but nothing else. If the string contains anything except letters or spaces, your method will break.

---

```
choice = Integer(gets.chomp)
```

This will throw an exception when the user enters a non-number. You might perhaps catch that exception and give the user something a bit more friendly than an exception-message.

---

```
#make sure the message is in lowercase
plaintext.downcase!
```

Returning the result with the same case as the original had (instead of lower casing the input string and then using upper case letters in the translation) seems much preferable.

---

```
plaintext.split("").each do |c|
  ciphertext += $caesar_map[c]
end
```

Building strings up imperatively like this is often not very idiomatic ruby. In this case I'd use `gsub`:

```
plaintext.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/) do |c|
  $caesar_map[c]
end
```

Since this only replaces letters and leaves everything else as-is, this also gets rid of your problem of not supporting non-letters (and gets rid of the need to special-case " " in the map).

If you follow my advice from earlier and get rid of the global map, you'll have to adjust the above appropriately, of course.

---

```
$caesar_map.index c
```

Note that using `Hash#index` is `O(n)`, so this is terribly inefficient (same goes for when you used it earlier in `init`). If you follow my advice and don't use a map, this will be much more inefficient.

---

In summary, here's how I'd implement the en- and decoding:

```
# Shifts a given letter by key places in the alphabet, wrapping around after "z",
# keeping the case in tact.
# Do not call with anything that's not a letter between a and z (or A and Z)
def shift_letter(letter, key)
  case letter
  when "a".."z"
    base = "a".bytes[0]
  when "A".."Z"
    base = "A".bytes[0]
  end

  # Set letter_index to the index of the given letter (i.e. 0 for A or a, 1 for b etc.)
  letter_index = letter.bytes[0] - base

  # Calculate the index of the mapped letter
  mapped_index = (letter_index + key) % 26

  # Convert index back to letter
  (base + mapped_index).chr
end

# Encrypts a plaintext message using the Caesar Cipher
def encode(plaintext, key)
  # Replace each letter in the string with the result of shifting
  # that letter by key places
  plaintext.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/) do |c|
    shift_letter(c, key)
  end
end

# Decrypts a ciphertext message using the Caesar Cipher
def decode(ciphertext, key)
  encode(ciphertext, -key)
end
```

Comment: (The upper case letters are the translate-to, not translate-from, hence the to_lower.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Right, good point. Doing it that way still seems strange to me.

Comment: Agreed; it threw me as well.