# Caesar Cipher implementation - Odin Project

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I am going through the Odin Project Ruby section, and just finished implementing a Caesar cipher interpretation.  Should I use classes, or more than one method to distribute the flow?  Is there really a need for initialization in this?

```
def caesar_cipher(string, shifter)
    ciphered = []
    string.split("").each do |char|
        if char == " " then ciphered << char 
            next 
        end

        char = char.to_s.ord

        if ("a".ord.."z".ord).include? char
            if char + shifter < "z".ord
                ciphered.push((char + shifter).chr)
            else
                ciphered.push((shifter - ("z".ord - char) + "a".ord).chr)
            end         
        elsif ("A".ord.."Z".ord).include? char
            if char + shifter < "Z".ord
                ciphered.push((char + shifter).chr)
            else
                ciphered.push((shifter - ("Z".ord - char) + "A".ord).chr)
            end 
        else    
            next
        end

    end
    print ciphered.join + "\n"
end

#test: caesar_cipher("Hello friend my Name is Sam",10)
```

Comment: Please see some of the other solutions already discussed: [Learning Ruby Caesar Cipher](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55049/learning-ruby-caesar-cipher), [Caesar cipher in Ruby](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35317/caesar-cipher-in-ruby), [Menu-based Caesar Cipher with encryption and decryption](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7777/menu-based-caesar-cipher-with-encryption-and-decryption)

Answer (score 3):

The code can be simplified, but you're on the right track.

A function is sufficient for a simple string filter like this; a class would be overkill.  I would rename the first parameter to `plaintext` and the result to `ciphertext` because that is the standard terminology.

The function should return the ciphertext rather than printing it.  The caller should have the flexibility to print it, show it in a GUI, store it in a database, or whatever.

Instead of `split("").each`, you can iterate over the plaintext using `plaintext#each_codepoint`.  You can also build the result by appending to a string rather than joining a list.

The `if…elseif` would be slightly better as a `case` expression.  You don't need the special case for `" "`

```
def caesar_cipher(plaintext, shift)
  ciphertext = ''
  plaintext.each_codepoint do |asc|
    ciphertext << case asc
      when 'a'.ord..'z'.ord
        'a'.ord + (asc - 'a'.ord + shift) % 26
      when 'A'.ord..'Z'.ord
        'A'.ord + (asc - 'A'.ord + shift) % 26
      else
        asc
    end
  end
  ciphertext
end
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!  What does the each_codepoint method do?

Comment: [`String#each_codepoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_codepoint) is like `each_char` but yields the `ord` of each character.

Comment: That is awesome, thanks!  Also, I forgot the syntax of the case when statement that in each when you just specify the condition and don't need to repeat "asc in..".  Very useful!

Comment: This is a good answer. It might be possible to simplify further by using `map` to obviate the need for the intermediary `ciphertext` variable.